# Group csv data using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this csv data:

```
LabebStoreId,catalog_uuid,lang,cat_0_name,cat_1_name,cat_2_name,cat_3_name,catalogname,description,properties,price,price_before_discount,externallink,Rating,delivery,discount,instock
6021,011DEN0800041,ar,منتجات المنزل والحدائق,مستلزمات التخزين المنزلية,دولاب ملابس,,فستان ديكاستا مع مرآة,ديكاستا مع مرآة,{},325.0,725.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/clothes-storage/pan-emirates-decasta-dresser-with-mirror/p/011DEN0800041,,التوصيل المجاني,55%,
6021,011DEN0800041,en,Home & Garden,Home Storage,Clothes Storage,,Pan Emirates DECASTA DRESSER WITH MIRROR,DECASTA DRESSER WITH MIRROR,{},325.0,725.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/clothes-storage/pan-emirates-decasta-dresser-with-mirror/p/011DEN0800041,,Free delivery,55%,
6021,011NFM2000029,ar,منتجات المنزل والحدائق,مستلزمات التخزين المنزلية,رفوف,,خزانة ملابس فورستون من بان الإمارات,خزانة ملابس 2 باب من فورستون,{},2795.0,5795.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/shelves/pan-emirates-forreston-2-door-sliding-wardrobe/p/011NFM2000029,,التوصيل المجاني,51%,
6021,011NFM2000029,en,Home & Garden,Home Storage,Shelves,,Pan Emirates FORRESTON 2 DOOR SLIDING WARDROBE,FORRESTON 2 DOOR SLIDING WARDROBE,{},2795.0,5795.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/shelves/pan-emirates-forreston-2-door-sliding-wardrobe/p/011NFM2000029,,Free delivery,51%,
6021,025ULT2000018,en,Home & Garden,Living Room & Home Decor,"Chairs, Bean Bags & Ottomans",Chairs & Tools,Pan Emirates CAMION DINING CHAIR,CAMION DINING CHAIR,{},325.0,650.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/chairs-tools/pan-emirates-camion-dining-chair/p/025ULT2000018,,Free delivery,50%,
6021,035CJM3700084,en,Home & Garden,Living Room & Home Decor,Sofas & Sofa Beds,,Pan Emirates Tataway Sofa Bed,TATAWAY SOFA BED,{},1225.0,1750.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/sofas-sofa-beds/pan-emirates-tataway-sofa-bed/p/035CJM3700084,,Free delivery,30%,
6021,035IVF1000002,en,Home & Garden,Living Room & Home Decor,Sofas & Sofa Beds,,Pan Emirates Rosepond 2 Seater Sofa,ROSEPOND 2 SEATER SOFA,{},995.0,2150.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/sofas-sofa-beds/pan-emirates-rosepond-2-seater-sofa/p/035IVF1000002,,Free delivery,53%,
6021,041AMY1400055,ar,منتجات المنزل والحدائق,ديكور المنزل وغرفة المعيشة,الكراسي ، بين باغس وغيرها,كراسي وأدوات,كرسي إكزافييه من بان الإمارات,كرسي XAVIER,{},275.0,575.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/chairs-tools/pan-emirates-xavier-chair/p/041AMY1400055,,التوصيل المجاني,52%,
6043,1005372,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,البقالة,المنزل,أساسيات المنزل,لولو سائل ملمع الأحذية الفوري بني محايد ٧٥ مل,انفض الغبار عن الحذاء وحافظ على مظهر حذائك في أفضل حالاته مع سائل تلميع الأحذية من لولو بني محايد. تم تصميمه لإطالة عمر أحذيك باستعادة لمعانه الأصلي. يأتي سائل تلميع الأحذية في زجاجة مدمجة مع قضيب إسفنجي في الأعلى لتطبيق خالي من الفوضى. يمكنك حمل زجاجة تلميع الأحذية الفوري إلى العمل أو في رحلات العمل حيث تحتاج إلى ترك انطباع متألق في كل خطوة.,"{""b"": ""75ml"", ""النوع"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""c"": ""LuLu PL"", ""a"": ""Shoe Polish""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/lulu-instant-shoe-shine-liquid-neutral-brown-75ml/p/1005372,0.0,"توصيل للمنزل   حسب الوقت المحدد ,تسوق واستلم أكثر سهولة ",50% خصم,labeb
6043,1005372,en,Home,Grocery,Household,Home Essentials,LuLu Instant Shoe Shine Liquid Neutral Brown 75ml,Dust off the dust and keep your shoes looking their best with the Lulu Neutral Brown Instant Shoe Shine Liquid. It is formulated to extend the life of your footwear by restoring its original shine. This shoe shine liquid comes in a compact bottle with a sponge applicator at the top for mess-free application. You can carry this bottle of instant shoe shine to work or on business trips where you need to make a sparkling impression with every step.,"{""Content"": ""75ml"", ""Type"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""Brand"": ""LuLu PL""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/en-ae/lulu-instant-shoe-shine-liquid-neutral-brown-75ml/p/1005372,0.0,"Home Delivery   As per selected slot ,Click & Collect Collect from store",50% off,labeb
6043,1005374,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,البقالة,المنزل,أساسيات المنزل,لولو سائل ملمع فوري للأحذية الرياضية 75 مل,,"{""b"": ""75ml"", ""النوع"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""c"": ""LuLu PL"", ""a"": ""Shoe Polish""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/lulu-instant-sport-shoe-shine-liquid-75ml/p/1005374,0.0,"توصيل للمنزل   حسب الوقت المحدد ,تسوق واستلم أكثر سهولة ",50% خصم,labeb
6043,1005374,en,Home,Grocery,Household,Home Essentials,LuLu Instant Sport Shoe Shine Liquid 75ml,,"{""Content"": ""75ml"", ""Type"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""Brand"": ""LuLu PL""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/en-ae/lulu-instant-sport-shoe-shine-liquid-75ml/p/1005374,0.0,"Home Delivery   As per selected slot ,Click & Collect Collect from store",50% off,labeb
6043,mp-00001713,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,Realme,,,"Realme 7 6GB RAM 64GB Mist Blue 4G, RMX2155","The Oppo Realme 7 is part of the new generation of flagships from the Realme brand. With a 6.5-inch Full HD + screen, the Realme 7 has a Mediatek Helio G95 processor with variants of 4GB or 6GB of RAM with 64GB of internal storage, or 8GB of RAM with 128GB of storage, expandable via microSD. The rear camera of the Realme 7 is made up of four 48 MP, 8 MP, 2MP and 2MP lenses, and a 16 megapixel front camera and completes its technical specifications with a 5000 mAh battery with support for fast charging, fingerprint reader. mounted on its side, and Android 10 as the operating system.","{""Internal Memory"": ""64GB"", ""SIM Count"": ""Dual"", ""Network"": ""4G"", ""Screen Size"": ""6.5in"", ""RAM"": ""6GB"", ""Battery Size"": ""5000mAh"", ""Operating System Version"": ""Android 11"", ""Display Type"": ""IPS LCD"", ""Refresh Rates"": ""90hz"", ""Model No"": ""RMX2155"", ""Color"": ""Blue"", ""Product dimension"": ""162.3 x 75.4 x 9.4 mm"", ""Weight"": ""196.5g""}",559.00,,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/realme-7-6gb-ram-64gb-mist-blue-4g-rmx2155/p/mp-00001713,0.0,توصيل للمنزل   التوصيل خلال 3 إلى 5 أيام,44% خصم,
```

And I would like to group them by `LabebStoreId`, `catalog_uuid` and `lang` like this:

```
LabebStoreId,catalog_uuid,lang,cat_0_name,cat_1_name,cat_2_name,cat_3_name,catalogname,description,properties,price,price_before_discount,externallink,Rating,delivery,discount,instock
6021,011DEN0800041,ar,منتجات المنزل والحدائق,مستلزمات التخزين المنزلية,دولاب ملابس,,فستان ديكاستا مع مرآة,ديكاستا مع مرآة,{},325.0,725.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/clothes-storage/pan-emirates-decasta-dresser-with-mirror/p/011DEN0800041,,التوصيل المجاني,55%,
6021,011DEN0800041,en,Home & Garden,Home Storage,Clothes Storage,,Pan Emirates DECASTA DRESSER WITH MIRROR,DECASTA DRESSER WITH MIRROR,{},325.0,725.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/clothes-storage/pan-emirates-decasta-dresser-with-mirror/p/011DEN0800041,,Free delivery,55%,
6043,1005372,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,البقالة,المنزل,أساسيات المنزل,لولو سائل ملمع الأحذية الفوري بني محايد ٧٥ مل,انفض الغبار عن الحذاء وحافظ على مظهر حذائك في أفضل حالاته مع سائل تلميع الأحذية من لولو بني محايد. تم تصميمه لإطالة عمر أحذيك باستعادة لمعانه الأصلي. يأتي سائل تلميع الأحذية في زجاجة مدمجة مع قضيب إسفنجي في الأعلى لتطبيق خالي من الفوضى. يمكنك حمل زجاجة تلميع الأحذية الفوري إلى العمل أو في رحلات العمل حيث تحتاج إلى ترك انطباع متألق في كل خطوة.,"{""b"": ""75ml"", ""النوع"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""c"": ""LuLu PL"", ""a"": ""Shoe Polish""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/lulu-instant-shoe-shine-liquid-neutral-brown-75ml/p/1005372,0.0,"توصيل للمنزل   حسب الوقت المحدد ,تسوق واستلم أكثر سهولة ",50% خصم,labeb
6043,1005372,en,Home,Grocery,Household,Home Essentials,LuLu Instant Shoe Shine Liquid Neutral Brown 75ml,Dust off the dust and keep your shoes looking their best with the Lulu Neutral Brown Instant Shoe Shine Liquid. It is formulated to extend the life of your footwear by restoring its original shine. This shoe shine liquid comes in a compact bottle with a sponge applicator at the top for mess-free application. You can carry this bottle of instant shoe shine to work or on business trips where you need to make a sparkling impression with every step.,"{""Content"": ""75ml"", ""Type"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""Brand"": ""LuLu PL""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/en-ae/lulu-instant-shoe-shine-liquid-neutral-brown-75ml/p/1005372,0.0,"Home Delivery   As per selected slot ,Click & Collect Collect from store",50% off,labeb
6021,011NFM2000029,ar,منتجات المنزل والحدائق,مستلزمات التخزين المنزلية,رفوف,,خزانة ملابس فورستون من بان الإمارات,خزانة ملابس 2 باب من فورستون,{},2795.0,5795.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/shelves/pan-emirates-forreston-2-door-sliding-wardrobe/p/011NFM2000029,,التوصيل المجاني,51%,
6021,011NFM2000029,en,Home & Garden,Home Storage,Shelves,,Pan Emirates FORRESTON 2 DOOR SLIDING WARDROBE,FORRESTON 2 DOOR SLIDING WARDROBE,{},2795.0,5795.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/shelves/pan-emirates-forreston-2-door-sliding-wardrobe/p/011NFM2000029,,Free delivery,51%,
6043,1005374,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,البقالة,المنزل,أساسيات المنزل,لولو سائل ملمع فوري للأحذية الرياضية 75 مل,,"{""b"": ""75ml"", ""النوع"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""c"": ""LuLu PL"", ""a"": ""Shoe Polish""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/lulu-instant-sport-shoe-shine-liquid-75ml/p/1005374,0.0,"توصيل للمنزل   حسب الوقت المحدد ,تسوق واستلم أكثر سهولة ",50% خصم,labeb
6043,1005374,en,Home,Grocery,Household,Home Essentials,LuLu Instant Sport Shoe Shine Liquid 75ml,,"{""Content"": ""75ml"", ""Type"": ""Shoe Polish"", ""Brand"": ""LuLu PL""}",2.90,5.75,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/en-ae/lulu-instant-sport-shoe-shine-liquid-75ml/p/1005374,0.0,"Home Delivery   As per selected slot ,Click & Collect Collect from store",50% off,labeb
6021,025ULT2000018,en,Home & Garden,Living Room & Home Decor,"Chairs, Bean Bags & Ottomans",Chairs & Tools,Pan Emirates CAMION DINING CHAIR,CAMION DINING CHAIR,{},325.0,650.0,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/chairs-tools/pan-emirates-camion-dining-chair/p/025ULT2000018,,Free delivery,50%,
6043,mp-00001713,ar,الصفحة الرئيسية,Realme,,,"Realme 7 6GB RAM 64GB Mist Blue 4G, RMX2155","The Oppo Realme 7 is part of the new generation of flagships from the Realme brand. With a 6.5-inch Full HD + screen, the Realme 7 has a Mediatek Helio G95 processor with variants of 4GB or 6GB of RAM with 64GB of internal storage, or 8GB of RAM with 128GB of storage, expandable via microSD. The rear camera of the Realme 7 is made up of four 48 MP, 8 MP, 2MP and 2MP lenses, and a 16 megapixel front camera and completes its technical specifications with a 5000 mAh battery with support for fast charging, fingerprint reader. mounted on its side, and Android 10 as the operating system.","{""Internal Memory"": ""64GB"", ""SIM Count"": ""Dual"", ""Network"": ""4G"", ""Screen Size"": ""6.5in"", ""RAM"": ""6GB"", ""Battery Size"": ""5000mAh"", ""Operating System Version"": ""Android 11"", ""Display Type"": ""IPS LCD"", ""Refresh Rates"": ""90hz"", ""Model No"": ""RMX2155"", ""Color"": ""Blue"", ""Product dimension"": ""162.3 x 75.4 x 9.4 mm"", ""Weight"": ""196.5g""}",559.00,,https://www.luluhypermarket.com/ar-ae/realme-7-6gb-ram-64gb-mist-blue-4g-rmx2155/p/mp-00001713,0.0,توصيل للمنزل   التوصيل خلال 3 إلى 5 أيام,44% خصم,
```

I tried doing that using pandas but it didn't seems to be generating the expected output:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])
grouped_df = df.groupby(['LabebStoreId'], group_keys=False, as_index=False).apply(lambda grouped_df: grouped_df.sort_values(by=['catalog_uuid']))
```

Comment: Why does your desired result have two rows for `6021,011DEN0800041`? Shouldn't they be combined into a single row since they have the same `LabebStoreId` and `catalog_uuid`?

Comment: Actually some records contains multiple languages `en` and `ar` that is why two rows one row per language.

Comment: So you want to group by `LabebStoreId`, `catalog_uuid`, and `language`? Why didn't you say that? Also, if you're grouping, you need to specify how all the other columns will be aggregated into the combined rows.

Comment: What are you doing with `.apply()`? The `lambda` receives a single row of the grouped df, what are you trying to sort there?

Comment: I was trying to sort the data frame by `catalog_uuid` to later save the df into the csv.

Comment: Then just do that to the whole dataframe, don't do it in `.apply()` -- that's for row-wise operations.

Comment: `sorted_df = grouped_df.sort_values(...)`

Comment: `df.groupby(['LabebStoreId', 'catalog_uuid', 'language'], ...)`

Comment: `sorted_df = grouped_df.sort_values(by=['catalog_uuid'])` gives `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`

Comment: Right, `groupby()` doesn't return a new dataframe, it returns an object that you can perform aggregation on, like `.sum()`, `.mean()`, etc. These return the new dataframe with the specified aggregation. Grouping without aggregation doesn't make sense, as I mentioned above. So it's not clear what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend polars over pandas for multiple aggregation clauses. Your code would look something like this:

```
    import polars as pl
    dataset = pl.read_csv(url, dtype=dtypes)

from .dataset import dataset

q = (
    dataset.lazy()
    .groupby(["LabeStoreID", "catalog_uuid", "lang")
    .sort("catalog_uuid")
)

df = q.collect()
```

more docs here : https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/groupby.html

Comment: I am getting `pyo3_runtime.PanicException: this operation is not implemented/valid for this dtype: List(Utf8)` at `df = q.collect()`

Comment: please make sure you are initializing the csv read using polars- i forgot to mention that above

Comment: your solutions doesn't worked for me. It is only giving me 3 columns which is `LabebStoreId`, `lang`(list), `catalog_uuid`(list)

Comment: Please try edited solution- I thought you needed some aggregation, which is why your original post contained a lambda function. 

You essentially just need to group on those columns? This should produce the desired output

Comment: it seems like it is working. Any idea how to overcome this `AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'write_csv'` ? I'd like to export that df to csv

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_csv.html

polars requires you to collect the lazyframe into a dataframe object

You can also directly instantiate a dataframe using the eager API and then call .write_csv